# Map two ArrayList with different sizes

Tags: java, android, arraylist, dictionary, hashmap

For Example:

```
ArrayList1 = {userid1, userid2, userid1, userid4, userid1, userid3, userid2, userid4, userid4, userid4, userid2};

ArrayList2 = {username1, username2, username3, username4};
```

Mapping these two array so that whenever I call `ArrayList1.get(0).getUserName()`, it should provide me with `username1`.

Comment: Show your attempts please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way to do that and that is by using `HashMap`:

```
//create your custom object which will be mapped
public class User{
  public String userId;
  public String userName;
}


ArrayList<String> userKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();
```

Now using a userKey, you can access its corresponding userData;

Example:

```
User user = users.get("yourKey");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class User {
        String username;

        public User(String username)
        {
            this.username = username;
        }
        /**
         * @return the username
         */
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        /**
         * @param username the username to set
         */
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
    }
```

`userid1, userid2`... must be `User` objects

```
User userid1 = new User("username1");    
User userid2 = new User("username2");
```

Initialize all the user objects

```
ArrayList1 = {userid1, userid2, userid1, userid4, userid1, userid3, userid2, userid4, userid4, userid4, userid2};
```

Then you can call

```
   String username =  ArrayList1.get(0).getUserName();
```

this will return `username1`

Comment: Mark as answer if you are okay with this

Comment: But what if the list is dynamic, I can't add the username string manually for all!

Comment: This is just a sample. If you have a model class like "User" class, you can dynamically create objects to "User" class and hold it in "ArrayList<User>"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use :

```
List<List<T>> = ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>;
```

T is the class of you UserName.

Answer (score 0):

Use HashSet instead of arraylist. Set does not allow duplicate.

Comment: If This answer is Useful then please Vote for positive.